# Fixing a zero GUID for a VSTO addin

Tags: c#, windows-installer, vsto

I'm having a little trouble setting a real (non-zero) GUID for an installed add-in.

First off, the installer works fine, and the installed add-in seems fully functional. I can also manage it in all the usual Officey ways. However, the Event Viewer reports the addin startup with a zero GUID:

```
Name: <name>
Description: <name>
ProgID: <name>
GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Load Behavior: 3
HKLM: 0
Location: file:///<file>|vstolocal
Boot Time (Milliseconds): <value>
```

All the other addins have a real GUID, and I don't want to look out of place. The code starts as follows:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("ADD95DAF-9D0D-4B16-BEA5-4CFDBCF40791")]
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
...
}
```

The install log contains registry writing as follows.

```
RegOpenKey(,Key=<name>,,BinaryType=0,,)
RegAddValue(Name=CLSID,Value={ADD95DAF-9D0D-4B16-BEA5-4CFDBCF40791},)
RegOpenKey(,Key=CLSID\{ADD95DAF-9D0D-4B16-BEA5-4CFDBCF40791}\InProcServer32,,BinaryType=0,,)
RegAddValue(,Value=<file>.dll,)
RegOpenKey(,Key=CLSID\{ADD95DAF-9D0D-4B16-BEA5-4CFDBCF40791}\ProgId,,BinaryType=0,,)
RegAddValue(,Value=<name>,)
RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483647,Key=Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<name>,,BinaryType=0,,)
RegAddValue(Name=Description,Value=<name>,)
RegAddValue(Name=FriendlyName,Value=<name>,)
RegAddValue(Name=LoadBehavior,Value=#3,)
RegAddValue(Name=Manifest,Value=file:///<file>.vsto|vstolocal,)
RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483647,Key=Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\FormRegions\IPM.Note,,BinaryType=0,,)
RegAddValue(Name=<name>.FeedbackRegion,Value==<name>,)
```

Where  and  are appropriate (and as far as I can tell correct) values.

I'm obviously missing something. Any ideas what?

Comment: So I found one issue in the above, but it wasn't enough. The first CLSID association is using a name rather than a key and a default value.

Comment: So the issue has not been resolved?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul No, it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this, maybe you can get some ideas to check things yourself. This might all be obvious to you, please bear with me as we narrow things down:

- Are you sure of the bitness of your addin and the office installation? As in; is your Office installation 64 bit or 32 bit? And what is your addin?
- Did you check [**github.com**](http://github.com) for [sample code doing similar stuff](https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/blob/977013cfbd4317279567fdec72f194c3bd4b8a16/TemplateCS/Addin/ThisAddIn.cs)? (to see how other people do things - obviously - I find that this can help speed things up quite a bit sometimes).
- Did you search your project for that zero GUID? Maybe it is defined in the project properties somewhere?
- And going a bit off the beaten track: how is Office installed? Is it an `App-V package`? How do you install your stuff? Is it an `MSI package`?

Comment: Good questions all. (a) it's my addin, and it's testing okay on x86 and x64. I do fiddle to make the registry happy in all cases, as Office can be x86 on an x64 system. So I might have missed something, but as I said, the functioning is fine. (b) That link is very cool, and has all sorts of nice tricks that help with macros, but nothing obvious I've missed. I'll check the [ProgId] one though. (c) Definitely no zero GUIDs anywhere, even used grep to be safe. (d) Office install is an MSI.

Comment: Did you solve this peoblem ? please guide me i am having the same issue